# How can I convert a RAW (DNG) photo to a JPG on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app, file-conversion

I have an iPhone 14 Pro. There are some photos that were taken in RAW (DNG) format. I want those photos to be in JPG format. I have the Photos app's "Transfer to Mac or PC" setting on "Automatic", but when I transfer the photos to my PC, they are still in DNG format.

I tried to use ImageMagick on my PC to convert the DNG files to JPG, but as you can see (original DNG on the left side, converted JPG on the right side), the colors are way off on the converted image:

[image]

So I would like to do the conversion in the iPhone itself if possible. I found an [article](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-convert-proraw-to-jpeg-on-iphone/) saying that you can convert a DNG photo to a JPG by tapping the Share button on the image and then selecting "Save to Files", but that still saved the photo as a DNG.

Comment: Shortcuts has a "convert image" action which should allow to covert DNG to JPG.

Comment: That works, although it was not obvious to me on how to set it up (never used the Shortcuts app before). Would you like to post a full answer, or I can do it later?

Comment: Just post an answer yourself and include a screenshot of the shortcut created. Glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @nohillside for mentioning the "Convert Image" action in the Shortcuts app.

I created a shortcut to add a "Convert to JPG" item on a photo's Share menu by performing these steps:

1. Open the Shortcuts app.
2. Tap on `+`.
3. Tap on `Add Action`.
4. In the `Search for apps and actions` box, type in "convert".
5. You should see `Convert Image` - tap on that.
6. Rename the shortcut to "Convert to JPG".
7. The top of the screen should show `Convert Image to JPEG`, with both `Image` and `JPEG` being modifiable.
8. Change `Image` to `Shortcut Input`.
9. Now the top of the screen should show `Receive Any input from Nowhere`, with both `Any` and `Nowhere` being modifiable.
10. Change `Any` to just `Images`.
11. Change `Nowhere` to `Share Sheet`.
12. Tap `Save to Photo Album` to add a step to `Save Converted Image to Recents`.
13. The shortcut should look like the following. Then tap `Done`.

[image]

After creating this shortcut, when I tap the Share button on a photo, I can see the `Convert to JPG` shortcut on the Share menu:

[image]

NOTE: I have noticed that the converted JPEG files are missing several EXIF tags (such as the time zone offset) that are present in the original DNG images. I don't know why that is happening.

Comment: where is the converted image found ?

Comment: If you follow the above steps, you can find the converted one next to the original. You can identify based on the size, JPEG takes much less space than DNG.